# Async function takes twice the time if there's components in the screen - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an async function that calculates the price of a product. If I test it in a blank screen, it takes ~5 seconds. If I use it in the actual screen (that has a lot of components) it takes ~10 seconds.

It's the same code (CTRL C, CTRL V) executing on useEffect.

Should I use another hook?

**UPDATE:**

Now I'm reproducing the same behavior in the same screen.

```js
return <></>;

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Header
      title="Pedido"
      navigation={navigation}
      showBackButton={true}
      showCart={true}
      showBell={true}
    />
```

If I leave the code this way, the function in useEffect takes 5 seconds to return. If I comment the first return line, the same function takes more than 10 seconds to return.

That's the only change in both scenarios!

**UPDATE 2**

The code in useEffect is a test of a function. It has no relation with the components in the screen.

**UPDATE 3**

I found the villain. It's an ActivityIndicator in the screen. Without it the function takes the same 5 seconds to return.

Does it make any sense?

**UPDATE 4**

Same thing with an animated gif

Comment: Please add more information as this question is very broad. [Help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It's **very** hard to answer this without seeing your `useEffect` code and the surrounding context.

Are you measuring the actual function call time? Remember that `useEffect` is called after the render is complete, and it sounds like you have a fairly complex render on the second screen — it will naturally take longer for the function call to start if rendering is taking longer.

Is it possible the component that includes the `useEffect` call is being rendered more than once? `useEffect` is called on each render, so maybe you're seeing the results of more than one render.

Is it possible your `useEffect` hook is dependent on another property that is changing? In other words:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your async function call
});
```

will only be called once per render, but

```
useEffect(() => {
  // your async function call
}, [someProperty])
```

will be called anytime `someProperty` changes.

Comment: The useEffect code is the same code on both screens. I copied and pasted the code from the test screen.

The code is something like that:

const begin = new Date();
const price = await calculate();
console.log(new Date() - begin);